# Can't boot into windows after installing xubuntu i384 - Tried many things

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu

So after a night full of tries, I finally decided to give up and ask here.
I've installed xubuntu i384 on my PC which usually runs on win 10.
After following carefully a guide I saw on the internet how to install xubuntu everything went smooth ( I made sure I chose something else and not to overwrite my windows). 
Whatsoever, I can't boot into windows. I Tried :

1. The "fix GRUB" `sudo upgrade-grub`command I saw on a many threads here. Tried it with both superuser permissions and without but no luck.
2. Boot Repair:  After I couldn't figure out how to use it within I burned it onto a USB stick I have using rufus and tried to boot it
       - the x64 version actually booted but It said I should use the x32 version - which won't even boot.
3. Tried burning windows image on a USB stick to go the Troubleshooting screen but it's still won't detect my windows.

   Any Help?

Edit : 
After trying boot repair and installing it from terminal now I'm stuck in bios where neither (Windows and ubuntu) aren't working and now I can't boot.
I tried to boot windows once again using a USB stick that I burned an ISO of windows 10 on it - whatsoever it still only leads to the purple installation screen and none of the troubleshooting options are working.
I tried going further on the windows installation and found out the windows partition (or at least the one I think) was unallocated (and apparentely empty) after allocating it ubuntu won't boot. 
In a need of some deseperate help.

Comment: What "fix GRUB" command have you used? Possibly `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: Indeed that's the one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: Nope, terminal says Gedit command not found

Comment: GEdit is just a text editor. You can use other editors such as nano, vi. Or you can install GEdit using `sudo apt install gedit`.

Answer (score 1):

Add ppa : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair` 
Update : `sudo apt update` 
run boot-repair : `boot-repair` **select Recomended Repair** 
update grub : `sudo update-grub`
reboot pc :`reboot`

Comment: Tried the boot repair and it says no such thing (boot repair wasn't installed although I tried doing so through terminal)

Comment: Insert `sudo apt install boot-repair` after `sudo apt update`.

Comment: did you add ppa ? @SyCo

Comment: nope, will try as I get home and will update

Comment: boot-repair command still doesn't work

Comment: can you tell me about the error found when you hit boot-repair command?